# How do you abstract the information to be displayed in a screen?

Tags: c++, architecture, abstraction, reusability

I'm writing an application that requires me to write information to a TFT display (kinda like a gameboy display).
I'm outputting the information to the display line by line. The way I'm doing it now requires me to have a function for each different screen.
Like:

```
void displayWelcomeMessage();
void displayInsertCoinMessage();
void displayGoodByeMessage();
```

Each function follows this logic:

```
void displaWelcomeMessage()
{
  writeline(0, "Hi David");
  writeline(1, "Welcome");
  writeline(2, "Back!");
}
```

Problem: I hate to have a different function for each screen. It's not scalable at all, imagine if I had 500 different screens. 
How do I abstract the process of writing to the display? So that I end up with a single generic function responsible for writing to the display.

Thank you

---

### Update

Following "Useless's" and Michael.P's advice, what I will probably end up doing is storing the format of each message in a file:

#### DisplayMessages.cfg

```
WELCOME_MESSAGE_1 = "Hi %name"
WELCOME_MESSAGE_2 = "Welcome"
WELCOME_MESSAGE_3 = "back!"
```

And in the code I will do something like:

```
using Message = std::vector<QString>;

void login(){

 //Do Stuff...

 QString line
 Message welcomeMessage;

 line=getMessageStructureFromCfg("WELCOME_MESSAGE_1").arg(userName); // loads "Hi %name" and replaces %name with the content of userName
 welcomeMessage.pushBack(line); // pushes the first line to welcomeMessage

 line=getMessageStructureFromCfg("WELCOME_MESSAGE_2"); // loads "Welcome"
 welcomeMessage.pushBack(line); // pushes the second line to welcomeMessage

 line=getMessageStructureFromCfg("WELCOME_MESSAGE_3"); // loads "back!"
 welcomeMessage.pushBack(line); // pushes the third line to welcomeMessage

 displayMessage(welcomeMessage);

}

void displayMessage(Message const &msg) {
 int i = 0;
 for (auto &line : msg) {
   writeline(i, line);
   i++;
 }
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

PS: Further improvements can be made if the file containing the messages structure used JSON instead of plain text. This way you could just iterate the child members(the lines) of each message and process accordingly

Comment: In any case, you will write the code, in many functions (methods) or many classes, but you can define an interface (a pure virtual class) called `Displayer` which contains a method for exemple : `display` then you implement it in many classes such as : `WelcomeMessageDisplayer`, 'InsertCoinMessageDisplayer' ... then you treat all the objects as `Displayer`.

Comment: the problem is that, at the moment, I have 50 different display messages (50 different functions). That would mean I would have 50 different classes. There has to be a better way of doing this

Comment: Can you store these messages in a file? You could then put them into a vector, and iterate through as much of them as you need

Comment: I like that idea. That way I dont have to have a function per message (or a class per message). I updated my post

Comment: Note you still have some interleaved data & logic (the `getMessageStructureFromCfg`/`push_back` lines). You could aim to end up with just `fetchAndDisplay("WELCOME_MESSAGE")` automating that loop for you.

Comment: @LuísAbreu if all your methods print the messages in the same way, of course you don't need many functions nor many classes, and if you want to store messages in file, consider looking for i18n libraries to do the work.

Comment: The thing is, they didn't print messages in the _exact_ same way. Some messages (like the welcome message) need to contain specific run-time information (%name). While other messages don't take any arguments at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you abstract the information to be displayed in a screen?

The same way you abstract any information - you move the data out of the code and into a data structure.

Your `displayXMessage()` functions perform a fixed sequence of calls on a fixed sequence of hardcoded string literals. So, split the algorithm from the data the usual way, by passing the data as an argument:

```
using Message = std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>;

void displayMessage(Message const &msg) {
  for (auto &line : msg) {
    writeline(line.first, line.second);
  }
}
```

and call it with the appropriate data:

```
Message welcomeMsg { {0, "Hi David"}, 
                     {1, "Welcome"},
                     {2, "Back!"}
                   };
displayMessage(welcomeMsg);
```

Comment: really liked your approach! thank you. Pls see the update I made

Answer (score -1):

I think you will find a solution to all those kind of problems by learning design patterns. In this case in particular. [Strucural patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/structural_patterns) seem to be what you are looking for; you will then have to pick the pattern which fits the most what you are trying to do.

Comment: Shall someone explain why down-vote ? Design patterns are exactly made to answer those kind of problems, like class exponential multiplicity and such. It provides an adaptable solution to a common problem.

Comment: Probably because design patterns aren't _supposed_ to help you design your code: they're supposed to help you _describe and communicate_ the design you came up with. They're names for common solutions, not recipes to follow.

Comment: And on further thought (although I didn't downvote), I can't see how structural patterns are relevant here anyway.  This is really a simple code-level refactoring rather than an architecture.

Comment: You are true, even though I am still thinking that those very common solutions would clearly fit his problem and any similar ones he could enconter. Therefore, learning these names and the describtion of the patterns might, to my opinon, _help him understand how to abstract better_ and could give him tools to _improve the way he builds his code_. I admit this might be going to deep to answer a simple problem.

Comment: It's not necessarily too deep, I just think it's the wrong approach. Patterns provide a language for naming the solution once you have it, but you still have to actually solve your problem in the first place.